# How to use Regular Expression with COPY function in Dockerfile

Tags: regex, dockerfile

I need to deploy an application using docker, and I'm using Dockerfile. below you can find my Dockerfile.

```
# The image is internal, so I only added the rhel:7 part of it
FROM rhel:7
RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
VOLUME /tmp
COPY "my-application-[0-9\.]*(-SNAPSHOT)?\.jar" my-application.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Xms256m","-Xmx512m","-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/run/spring/config/cacerts","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom","-jar","my-application.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080 8443
```

The file created by the build process is in this format `my-application-1.2.3.jar` or `my-application-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar`, next to this file there is also a sources file generated next to it, `my-application-1.2.3-sources.jar`. So I want to copy only `my-application-1.2.3.jar`.

The regex I tried with dummy files is:
`my-application-[0-9\.]*(-SNAPSHOT)?\.jar`

I already tried the following without success:

1. `COPY *.jar my-application.jar`
2. `RUN /bin/bash -c 'find . -iregex "\.\/my-application-[0-9\.]*(-SNAPSHOT)?\.jar" -exec cp {} my-application.jar \;'`

I have very basic Java experience, but I need to deploy this application using docker.

Comment: `COPY` doesn't support regular expressions.

Comment: My recommendation is to fix your build process so it produces usable output.

Comment: Indeed, we just filtered the files in the Jenkins build script, and just use `COPY *.jar my-application.jar`

Comment: I suggest to check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010392/using-regex-in-docker-copy-for-digits it helped me with understanding wildcards for COPY