# Using regex in Docker COPY for digits

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Im trying to copy a file in docker with below format

```
database-20.2.1.zip
```

I have tried using something like below, but it does not seems to work

```
COPY databse-+([0-9]).+([0-9]).+([0-9]).zip /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/database.zip
```

Is this something that can be done in docker copy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dockerfile [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) uses shell globs, not regular expressions.  The actual implementation uses the Go [`filepath.Match`](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Match) syntax.  That syntax doesn't allow some of the combinations that regular expressions do: you can match any single digit `[0-9]`, or any number of characters `*`, but not any number of digits.

Depending on how strict you want to be about what files you'll accept and how consistent the filename format is, any of the following will work:

```sh
COPY database-[0-9][0-9].[0-9].[0-9].zip ./database.zip
COPY database-*.*.*.zip ./database.zip
COPY database-*.zip ./database.zip
```

In all cases note that the pattern can match multiple files in the build context.  If the right-hand side of `COPY` is a single file name (not ending with `/`) but the glob matches multiple files you will get a build error.  In this case that's probably what you want.